# loop problems in fetched json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm still fighting with this code, actually i'm trying to find a solution, everywhere, i tried many times all the whole day.
So, i have this code, i used the fetch API in order to get the values, i can iterate the first json because i need to get the id (from album json).
now i would use the loop in order to get the values from the 2nd json in order to put under each id got from the first json the values with the same id from the second json so "albumId" from photo.

Thanks in advance

```js
async function getUsers() {
  let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?albums";
  try {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function getPhotos() {
  let url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?photos";
  try {
    let res2 = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function renderUsers() {
  let albums = await getUsers();
  let html = "";
  albums.forEach((album) => {
    let htmlSegment = `<div class="user"><h2>${album.id}</h2></div>`;

    html += htmlSegment;
  });

  let container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.innerHTML = html;
}

renderUsers();
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your post what your actual question is. If you have problems with your code, please explain what they are; what should your code do vs what does it actually do

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two JSONs?

Comment: Between the 2 json there's only a relation, pratically the json albums has an "id" the same value can be found in photos with the name of albumiD, looks like the only common value, the problem is that what i would achieve is to have all the photos belonginf to id1 then all the photoes belonging to id 2 and so on.

Comment: What it actually does is to take the id's from albums, and sort them. now i would use a loop where i can put all the photoes that belongs to id1 under the id 1 and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call both `getUsers()` and `getPhotos()` in `renderUsers()`. Then you can find the elements of `photos` with the matching `albumId` and add the images to the HTML.

```js
async function getUsers() {
  let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?albums";
  try {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function getPhotos() {
  let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?photos";
  try {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function renderUsers() {
  let [albums, photos] = await Promise.all([getUsers(), getPhotos()]);
  let html = "";
  albums.forEach((album) => {
    html += `<div class="user"><h2>${album.id}</h2>`;
    let albumPhotos = photos.filter(p => p.albumId == album.id);
    albumPhotos.forEach(photo => {
      html += `<img src="${photo.url}">`;
    });
    html += '</div>';
  });

  let container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.innerHTML = html;
}

renderUsers();
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```